# Using a button hover to increase margin with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a really simple slider using 2 buttons the will increase the margin when hovered over. I would like the buttons to increase or decrease the margins continuously.

At the minute I can only get them to move in set chunks. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```js
var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var right = document.querySelector(".right");
var slide = document.querySelector(".slider");

left.onmouseover = function() {
  var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(slide).marginLeft;
  console.log(currentLeftMargin);

  // Element's style = number portion of current style, then do math, then add back on the unit
  slide.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) - 900) + "px";
}

right.onmouseover = function() {
  var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(slide).marginLeft;
  console.log(currentLeftMargin);

  // Element's style = number portion of current style, then do math, then add back on the unit
  slide.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) + 900) + "px";
}
```

````css
``` .slide-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.slider {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.slider:hover {}

.item {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
````

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need an interval which sets the margin at consequent steps, by creating an Interval with `setInterval(function(), milliseconds);`
To be able to terminate the interval and preventing of creating endless amounts of intervals, we need to store the ID of the Interval in a variable.

`iId = setInterval(function(), milliseconds);`

We then would terminate the interval if the mouse leaves the element by `clearInterval(IntervalID);`

As you used a css-transition to smoothen the animation, i had to fiddle abit with the steps of margin increase and decrease and the interval, so there aren't any "jumps".

```js
var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var right = document.querySelector(".right");
var slide = document.querySelector(".slider");

// Amount of Pixels the margin gets increased and decreased
let steps = 50;
// Amount of milliseconds after the margin will be adjusted again
let interval = 100;
// Variable to store IntervalID to be able to terminate it onmouseout
let iId;

left.onmouseover = function(){
  iId = setInterval(() => {
    var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(slide).marginLeft;
    // Element's style = number portion of current style, then do math, then add back on the unit
    slide.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) + steps) + "px";
  }, interval)
}
left.onmouseout = () => {
  clearInterval(iId);
}

right.onmouseover = function(){
  iId = setInterval(() => {
    var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(slide).marginLeft;
  
    // Element's style = number portion of current style, then do math, then add back on the unit
    slide.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) - steps) + "px";
  }, interval)
}
right.onmouseout = () => {
  clearInterval(iId);
}
```

```css
.slide-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.slider{
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  left:0;
  
  transition: all ease 0.25s;
}
.slider:hover{
  
}

.item{
  display:block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` to repeat the movement you're currently doing in `onmouseover` for it to keep advancing.
Remember to `clearInterval` in `onmouseout`
Here's an example

```js
var left = document.querySelector(".left");
var right = document.querySelector(".right");
var slide = document.querySelector(".slider");

var moveLeftInterval;
var moveRightInterval;
var moveLeft = () => {
  var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(slide).marginLeft;
  console.log(currentLeftMargin);

  // Element's style = number portion of current style, then do math, then add back on the unit
  slide.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) - 900) + "px";
}

var moveRight = () => {
  var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(slide).marginLeft;
  console.log(currentLeftMargin);

  // Element's style = number portion of current style, then do math, then add back on the unit
  slide.style.marginLeft = (parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) + 900) + "px";
}

left.onmouseover = function() {
  moveLeftInterval = setInterval(moveLeft, 200);
}

left.onmouseout = function() {
  clearInterval(moveLeftInterval);
}

right.onmouseover = function() {
  moveRightInterval = setInterval(moveRight, 200);
}


right.onmouseout = function() {
  clearInterval(moveRightInterval);
}
```

```css
.slide-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.slider {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}

.slider:hover {}

.item {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can use an interval which you set to update each frame of movement of the `.slide` element.

You can also use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` to limit the movement of the slider to its contents.

```js
let left = document.querySelector(".left");
let right = document.querySelector(".right");
let slide = document.querySelector(".slider");
let interval;
let frameDelta = 40;

let updateSlidePosition = delta => {
  var currentLeftMargin = getComputedStyle(slide).marginLeft;
  slide.style.marginLeft = Math.max(slide.offsetWidth * -1, Math.min(0, parseInt(currentLeftMargin, 10) + delta)) + "px";
}

left.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  interval = setInterval(() => updateSlidePosition(frameDelta * -1), 40);
})
left.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => clearInterval(interval));

right.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
  interval = setInterval(() => updateSlidePosition(frameDelta), 40);
})
right.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => clearInterval(interval));
```

```css
.slide-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

.slider {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  transition: margin-left 0.1s;
}

.slider:hover {}

.item {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fade"></div>
</div>
```